# Vertically center two overlapping divs

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm working on a mobile version of my website, and I'm having trouble vertically-centering two divs. Since it is a mobile site, my css needs to work on any type of screen resolution, so this is where I'm having the problem. Also, different images will be used depending on what page you are on, so the resolution of the image is not static either. I need a way to center both my image div and text div no matter their height or width.

I've made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hHMa/) here to start out with. As you can see, I chose the `green area` to be the "screen" for the phone, and I want both the picture to center vertically, and the text to be on top of the picture and center vertically as well. Any help?

What I have so far... (in my jsfiddle)

HTML:

```
    <div id = "screen">
<div class = "overlay" id = "picture"><img src = "http://www.startingtofeelit.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Tennis-Mean-Streets.jpg" /></div>
<div class = "overlay" id = "text">This is where the text would appear</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #screen {
width:360px;
height:640px;
background-color:#0f0;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
}

.overlay {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
}

#picture {

}

#picture img{
width:100%;

}

#text {
background-color:#000;
width:100%;
opacity:0.5;
color:#fff;

}
```

Comment: I'd use something like http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all...

Comment: Post your code or your question will most likely get closed.

Comment: @3rror404 He has a fiddle posted, in case you didn't notice

Comment: @LauriElias that's not the same thing. Read the FAQ

Answer (score 0):

For vertically centering you can set margin top/bottom to auto.
If I understand where you want the text, this should work.

Html

```
<div id = "screen">
    <div class = "overlay" id = "text">This is where the text would appear</div>
    <div class = "overlay" id = "picture"><img src = "http://www.startingtofeelit.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Tennis-Mean-Streets.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

and css

```
#screen {
    width:360px;
    height:640px;
    background-color:#0f0;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

#picture {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#picture img{
    width:100%;
}

#text {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    background-color:#000;
    width:100%;
    opacity:0.5;
    color:#fff;

}
```

Comment: I thought of that approach too, but this only centers the image. I need both the image to be centered on the screen, and the text to be centered on the screen as well. That's why I was thinking of making the class `overlay` to make their positions "absolute" (in regards to the relative position of their parent div). Setting their top to 50% does not work either without specifically knowing their height in the css so you can set a negative margin-top. Any idea for a quick fix?

Comment: I am having a hard time figuring out a way to do this without knowing the height. I'll try to get back to this in a bit.

Comment: Yeah if I knew the height it would be much easier. I could probably get the height at run-time with JavaScript and do some manipulation that way, but I'd much rather not have to resort to that. Let me know if you figure anything out!

Comment: I edited the answer with absolute positioning for the text. this centers the top of the text, which isn't perfect, but it's the best I've come up with so far as long as the text height doesn't vary dramatically.

Comment: That would be great if the text was a static height too... as you can see, it does not work if there are multiple lines of text... http://jsfiddle.net/5hHMa/3/

Answer (score 0):

So it doesn't seem like there is a pure css way to do it, so I ended up using jQuery instead. I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hHMa/4/) in case you want to see how I did it, but the jist of it was this.

On document load, find any item with class "overlay" and apply a negative margin-top of half it's height to center it. Because it already has a position of absolute and top:50%, this will vertically center the item.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".overlay").each(function(){
        $(this).css("margin-top", $(this)[0].scrollHeight/2*-1); 
    });
});
```

It's pretty simple, and I wish there was a way to do it in pure css, but this way works as well. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score -1):

After the discussion in the comments I've determined this question is not nearly thought out well enough to attempt to answer and so this will stay simply in hopes that someone else that finds this page is helped by the answer

***:::Initial answer:::***

This question is easily much more difficult than you've made it seem. If it's a matter of fitting the image to the viewport of the device there is no single css solution and a javascript solution will be needed.

Let me explain, if the image is much taller than it is wide then to fit the image to the screen you'd want to set the height to something like 90% of the height (give some padding for the text etc). however since the image is variable size if the width is the greater value you'll want the width to something like 90%. Herein lay the problem, you wont want both the height and the width of the image to be 90% as that would distort the image. So there will need to be some javascript to flop around some classes here.

After that the css gets a bit hairy also, if you're looking for an overlay to display the same based on any position the user clicks on an image (assuming this is a sort of gallery) rather than an absolute positioned item at the top and left of the document you'll want a `position: fixed;` element which is positioned on the viewport.

All described before would need a bit of javascript again because there is no easy way to center something that is `fixed` without using negative margins of half its width/height.

An example of such a thing is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/5hHMa/2/

Here we have the css for the very fixed case which you have presented.

```
.overlay {
    position:fixed;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top: -150px;
    margin-left: -150px;
}

#picture img{
    width: 300px;    
}

#text {
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:0.5;
    color:#fff;

}
```

Ideally what you would do is instead of using a fixed value for the margins and width as I have you would determine these values and set them using javascript.

It is hard to form a complete solution for your problem with the limited information given, however hopefully this gives you a push in the correct direction.

Comment: Like I said to @dagarrison, I knew there was a way to do it at run-time with JavaScript using the negative margin-top method, but I feel like there should be some type of way to do it using pure css. if this isn't the case, I will have to resort to using JS. Also, I already considered if the height is much more than the width. I set it so it always has 100% width (no matter what, I want it to fill the width of the screen), and it will clip the height (I set `overflow:hidden` in the "screen" div).

Comment: That is the kind of information you should include in your initial question. Also, if the height clips, what does it mean for the text to be centered?

Comment: I will clip the image if it is too high. It is not necessary to see the entire image for my purposes. If the text div gets too high, I will have it be vertically-scrollable so you can view the rest. I just want the text to be centered if it does not fill the height of the viewport.

Comment: So you want the text centered on top of the image, nowhere does your question state that. I've given up on this answer, hopefully someone can help you with your solution.

Comment: "I need a way to center both my image div and text div no matter their height or width."

"...and I want both the picture to center vertically, and the text to be on top of the picture and center vertically as well."

I stated twice that I wanted this. You obviously just aren't a very perceptive reader.

Comment: @jas7457 No need for insults. Your question is very ambiguous, be very specific when asking questions and people will be much more willing to help